# Show that a set defines a simplicial complex

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

> Let
>
> - $A_n := \left\{-n,\cdots,-1,1,\cdots,n\right\}$
> - $\Delta_n := \left\{ B \subseteq A \; \big\vert \; \#(\{-i,i\}\cap B)\leq 1 \; \forall 1 \leq i \leq n \right\}$
>
> Show that $\Delta_n$ is a simplical complex and calculate its
>   $f$vector.

This exercise should be somehow related to combinatorics. Unfortunately I did only find definitions related to geometric constructs, and did not understand them entirely.

Could you please tell me what I need to show that this set is a simplicial complex? How can that $f$ vector be calculated?

Comment: You have to show that each $\{k\}\subseteq A_n$ is in $\Delta _n$ and that for each $B\in Δ_n$ and $A\subseteq B$, also $A\inΔ_n$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex

Comment: To count the number of $k$-simplices, first count the number of subsets of size $k+1$ of $n$ and then multiply with $2^{k+1}$ (Can you see why)?

Comment: @StefanHamcke thank you for your comment! No, unfortunately I don't see why, can you give me a hint?

Comment: A $k$-simplex, that is an element of $Δ_n$ of size $k+1$, contains for $k+1$ numbers $i$ between $1$ and $n$ exactly one of $i,-i$, and the number of $k+1$-subsets of $n$ is $\binom n {k+1}$. Then for each choice of $k+1$ numbers we can choose if $i$ or $-i$ is in that set, i.e. $2^{k+1}$ possibilities.

Comment: @StefanHamcke thanks, I finally understand that. However, using this I can count the items of $\Delta_n$ with a specific length, but how can I use that to show that it is a simplical complex?

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, you have to show that a subset of an element of $Δ_n$ is again an element of $Δ_n$ (and that each singleton from $A_n$ is an element in $Δ_n$, but that property is only required if we want $A_n$ to be the vertex set of the complex).

Comment: @StefanHamcke yes, that became clear to me, and so did your way to count the *k*-simplexes. What I still don't understand is how I can use the way of counting to show that each subset of a subset of $\Delta_n$ is again a subset of $\Delta_n$. Can you please give me another hint?

Comment: The counting of the simplices and checking that it is a complex are two different issues. It should be quite elementary to show that a subset of an element of $\Delta_n$ is again an element of $\Delta_n$. I don't see where the problem is.

Comment: @StefanHamcke yes, that is what I thought. I was just confused how the counting was related. Am I right that this can be used to calculate the $f$-vector? If I understand the definition correctly, it should be $(f_0,f_1,\cdots,f_{d+1})$ where $f_k$ is the number of $k$-simplices. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's the $f$-vector. So have you been able to show that $\Delta_n$ is an abstract simplicial complex?

Comment: @StefanHamcke yes, thank you very much! With your help I finally understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you've been able to show that $Δ_n$ is a simplicial complex, I give here the solution for other people that come by

$Δ_n:=\{B⊆A_n\mid \#(\{−i,i\}∩B)≤1 \text{ for all }1≤i≤n\}$ is the set of subsets of $A_n$ which contain at most one of $i,-i$, for each $i$ between $1$ and $n$. It is clear that a subset of such a set $B$ satisfies the same property, so $Δ_n$ is a simplicial complex. We see that each $\{i\}$ and $\{-i\}$ is an element of $Δ_n$, so the vertex set of $Δ_n$ is just $A_n$.

This simplicial complex has a nice geometric interpretation: If we think of $i$ as the $i$-th unit basis vector of $\Bbb R^n$, and $-i$ its negation, then a $B$ in $Δ_n$ is the convex hull of some of these vectors, as long as it doesn't contain $i$ and $-i$ at the same time. That means a simplex is a standard-$k$-simplex or its reflection in the subspace spanned by a subset of $\{1,...,n\}$. The realization is actually 
$\{x\in\Bbb R^n\mid ||x||_1=1\}$ and this is homeomorphic to the $n-1$-dimensional sphere.

A $k$-simplex, that is an element of $Δ_n$ of size $k+1$, contains for $k+1$ numbers $i$ between $1$ and $n$ exactly one of $i,−i$, and the number of $k+1$-subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ is $\binom n{k+1}$. Then for each choice of $k+1$ numbers we can choose if either $i$ or $−i$ is in that set, i.e. $2^{k+1}$ possibilities. So $f_k=2^{k+1}\binom n{k+1}$. Note that the total number of simplices is $3^n$ so we have the identity
$$3^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k+1}\binom n{k+1}$$